# test all line in a file with awk and grep and if it match put them in an other file

Tags: awk, grep, regular-expression

Here is my file `test.csv`

```
bonjour|b|french;deutsch|french
hello|h|english;russian|french
gutentag|g|german;polish|french
ciao|i|italian|french
```

I would like to test if the third split by | is french (french can be in an other split so only the third one) and put all line that match this in an other file.

example :

```
bonjour|b|french;deutsch|french
```

`french;deutsch` match it

Something like `awk -F | '$3=="french"' file`

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F '[|;]' '$3 == "french"' file >newfile
```

This uses both `|` and `;` as field delimiters and does a string comparison between the third such field and the string `french`.  If the string matches, the line is outputted.  Any output is redirected to the file `newfile`.

If using *only* `|` as a delimiter, you would have to test with a regular expression on the start of the third field:

```
awk -F '|' '$3 ~ /^french;/' file >newfile
```

This detects the string `french;` at the start of the third field and outputs the line if it matches.

If `french` can occur anywhere in the third `|`-delimited field (e.g. as `dutch;french`), then you may want to relax that pattern a bit an use

```
awk -F '|' '$3 ~ /french/' file >newfile
```

---

`grep` would be a bit awkward to use here as it's more difficult to specify exactly what `|`-delimited field to match in:

```
grep '^\([[:alpha:]]\{1,\}|\)\{2\}french;' file >newfile
```

This matches a string of alphabetical characters (letters) followed by a `|` character, twice, and then the string `french;`.

With an extended regular expression:

```
grep -E '^([[:alpha:]]+\|){2}french;' file >newfile
```

Note that the `|` now needs to be escaped to not be interpreted as an alternation.

Again, if `french` can occur anywhere within the third field, you willl need to relax the expression a bit:

```
grep '^\([[:alpha:]]\{1,\}|\)\{2\}[^|]*french' file >newfile
```

or,

```
grep -E '^([[:alpha:]]+\|){2}[^|]*french' file >newfile
```

I've inserted `[^|]*`, which matches any stretch of non-`|` characters before the word `french` (for example, the string `dutch;`), and I've removed the `;` at the end of the word (or you could have replaced the `;` by `[;|]`).